How can one create a queue inside a record in VHDL?
I need to create a data structure in VHDL testbench to hold data after parsining text files. The data that occurs in the text files does not have a fixed per line structure. Rather, it appears as chunks. There is some variation in how different chunks are to be parsed. Since the amount of data in a chunk can vary, I need to be able to store it in a queue. This is trivial in C++ and Python and also SystemVerilog. But I can't find how to do this in VHDL.
I need a way to create queue of records as a member field of a different record, and also create a standalone queue of records. How can this be done in VHDL?
EDIT:
This is for testbench only, simulation only purpose. Not or synthesis.
In SystemVerilog I can can create queue by using [$] after the struct name. I can create members of struct that are queue themself as well merely by use of this notation. This makes it quite simple to create a struct that has queue of another struct which has queue inside it of another struct and so on. In VHDL a struct is called record.
The question is simply put: What is the VHDL version of SystemVerilog [$] that can be used to create queue in VHDL? I do not understand why people need to downvote this. Creating testbenches for complex designs is not a simple task.

5.4 Access types 5.4.1 General "An object declared by an object declaration is created by the elaboration of the object declaration and is denoted by a simple name or by some other form of name. In contrast, objects that are created by the
evaluation of allocators (see 9.3.7) have no simple name. Access to such an object is achieved by an access value returned by an allocator; the access value is said to designate the object." You need an LRM. An access type is analogous to a pointer and a record to a structure. Again, process types are synthesis ineligible, instead describe hardware.

This question is related to testbench. Thus, this is not related to synthesis at all.

I found this VHDL queue implementation on GitHub: heikoengel/vhdl-queue. Maybe it's worth checking out....

How you create your queue is going to matter.
If you create your queue as a protected type, without VHDL-2019 you cannot put it in a record.   Even with 2019, you can only put it in a record with other protected types.   So this is not a general purpose solution.
You can create a queue as a linked list and a package of methods that operate on it - such as @Nipo suggested.   In this case you can put it into a general record, however, the object that holds that record must be a variable because of limitations of pointers.
To allow the object that holds the record be a variable or signal, you need a singleton data structure.   This is a package with a protected type and an instance of the protected type (a shared variable is also in a package - often the same package).
In Open Source VHDL Verification Methodology (OSVVM), a FIFO/queue is implemented as a singleton in the ScoreboardGenericPkg.vhd.   You can find it on GitHub at:  https://github.com/OSVVM/OsvvmLibraries and the package at:  https://github.com/OSVVM/OSVVM/blob/main/ScoreboardGenericPkg.vhd.
To use it, you need an instance of the generic package with the types you need.  For std_logic_vector, you can use ScoreboardPkg_slv.vhd.   That package also shows how to create an instance of the package for any sort of type you need.   The Queue/FIFO that is part of the scoreboard is just as efficient as a stand alone queue package - other than when you create the package instance, you need to specify a match function (the implicitly defined "=" is ok to use if you are using it as just a queue) and a to_string function (you need to do this twice since the scoreboard allows different actual and expected values - but only a trivial amount of extra work on the package instance).
Use model for OSVVM FIFOs/queues is simple:
use osvvm.ScoreboardPkg_slv.all ; 
signal FIFO : ScoreboardIdType ;
. . . 
InitThings :  process
begin
  FIFO := NewID(FIFO'instance_name, Search => PRIVATE_NAME) ; 
  . . . 
end process ; 

SomeProc : process
. . .
  Push(FIFO, X"A5") ; 
. . .

SomeOtherProc : process
. . . 
   Slv8 := Pop(FIFO) ; 
. . . 

The call to NewID is a constructor - just like a call to New in SystemVerilog.   In VHDL, the language states you cannot call the method of a protected type from a declarative region.   The call to NewID indirectly calls a method of a protected type, so technically my interpretation is that this is not allowed (until the next revision of the language when we delete that line in the LRM).
That said, currently most simulators (except Cadence and Xilinx) allow you to call NewID from a declarative region.   So for most simulators, you do not need to call NewID in the process, but can instead call it in the declaration as below (again, this is slightly illegal, but it works and will be legal in the future):
signal FIFO : ScoreboardIdType := NewID("FIFO", Search => PRIVATE_NAME);

The type ScoreboardIdType is an ordinary type and can be put in a record of any sort.   OSVVM does its communication with verification components using records and the FIFOs for communicating bursts of data are indeed have the ID of the burst fifos is in the communication record.   From https://github.com/OSVVM/OSVVM-Common/blob/main/src/AddressBusTransactionPkg.vhd#L192, you will see:
  type AddressBusRecType is record
    -- Handshaking controls
    --   Used by RequestTransaction in the Transaction Procedures
    --   Used by WaitForTransaction in the Verification Component
    --   RequestTransaction and WaitForTransaction are in osvvm.TbUtilPkg
    Rdy                : RdyType ;
    Ack                : AckType ;
    -- Transaction Type
    Operation          : AddressBusOperationType ;
    -- Address to verification component and its width
    -- Width may be smaller than Address
    Address            : std_logic_vector_max_c ;
    AddrWidth          : integer_max ;
    -- Data to and from the verification component and its width.
    -- Width will be smaller than Data for byte operations
    -- Width size requirements are enforced in the verification component
    DataToModel        : std_logic_vector_max_c ;
    DataFromModel      : std_logic_vector_max_c ;
    DataWidth          : integer_max ;
    -- Burst FIFOs
    WriteBurstFifo     : ScoreboardIdType ; 
    ReadBurstFifo      : ScoreboardIdType ; 
    . . . 

For its initialization, in https://github.com/OSVVM/AXI4/blob/main/Axi4/src/Axi4Manager.vhd#L275, you will see:
    TransRec.WriteBurstFifo <= NewID("WriteBurstFifo",      ModelID, Search => PRIVATE_NAME) ;
    TransRec.ReadBurstFifo  <= NewID("ReadBurstFifo",       ModelID, Search => PRIVATE_NAME) ;


What is the basic description of singleton? You have written "This is a package with a protected type and an instance of the protected type (a shared variable is also in a package - often the same package)." but what does "singleton" actually mean? I think it means something (for example a VHDL protected type) that has only a single instance that is used and accessed from everywhere, but I believe I might be wrong. I only came across the word "singleton" in the OSVVM literature. VHDL allows shared variable in a package that are shared by all entities that use the package???

Your understanding is correct.   In class based programming it is a class that is declared in a way that one instance / usage of the class can be created.   Hence, in VHDL, you would have to create both the PT declaration, body, and instance in the package body and then a wrapper interface to interact with the singleton.

And yes all of this is perfectly legal VHDL code and well supported by simulators.   The OSVVM libraries are tested with GHDL, NVC, Aldec, Siemens, Synopsys VCS, and Cadence Xcelium.   Xilinx XSIM is a work in progress, but it is looking good.

The name given during NewID can be used to lookup the ID in a separate verification component (if Search is set to NAME or NAME_AND_PARENT).    This is done in the OSVVM AXI Memory VC and allows multiple Memory VC to share the same memory space.   This is needed for modeling Zynq which has multiple AXI4 Subordinate ports accessing the same memory space.   So I suspect VHDL+OSVVM can do more than SV+UVM.

I don't know SV enough to tell whether $ is actually the same as this. OTOH, I know You may design chained lists using access in VHDL.
Here is a simple queue:
  type my_queue_item;

  type my_queue is access my_queue_item;

  type my_queue_item is
  record
    chain : framed_queue;
    -- some item data
    integer foo;
  end record;

  type my_queue_root is access my_queue;

  procedure my_queue_init(
    variable root: inout my_queue_root)
  is
  begin
    root := new my_queue;
    root.all := null;
  end procedure;

  procedure my_queue_put(
    variable root: inout my_queue_root;
    foo : in integer)
  is
    variable item, chain : my_queue;
  begin
    item := new my_queue_item;
    item.all.foo := foo;
    item.all.chain := null;

    if root.all = null then
      root.all := item;
    else
      chain := root.all;
      while chain.all.chain /= null
      loop
        chain := chain.all.chain;
      end loop;
      chain.all.chain := item;
    end if;
  end procedure;

  procedure my_queue_get(
    variable root: inout my_queue_root;
    foo : out integer;
    dt : in time := 10 ns)
  is
    variable item : my_queue;
  begin
    while true
    loop
      if root.all /= null then
        item := root.all;
        root.all := root.all.chain;
        foo := item.foo;
        deallocate(item);
        return;
      end if;
      wait for dt;
    end loop;
  end procedure;

my_queue_get above is the blocking variant with an interval between polling. It could be a procedure returning immediately whether it popped an element.
Having the root itself as an access to first element allows to easily share and modify the root from multiple VHDL processes.
